# CakePHP model validation for checkboxes

Tags: validation, cakephp, checkbox, model

I have a Job model where I want to submit a form to my other action (not to save the data directly into the db just to pass it to my other action) and I should check whether the user has selected at least 1 checkbox.

Here is my view's snippet:

```
echo '<tr class="v-top">
        <td colspan=2>'.$this->Form->input('system_codes_filter', array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'multiple' => 'checkbox',
            'label' => '',
            'name' => 'system.codes.filter',
            'class' => 'floatLeft',
            'options' => array('System codes' => $this->Submit->getSystemCodes($systemcodes)),
            'selected' => array('*'))).
        '</td></tr>';
```

Here is my model's snippet:

```
public $validate = array(
    'system_codes_filter' => array(
        'rule' => array('multiple', array(
            'min' => 1,
            'message' => 'Please select at least on system code!'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

As far as I know the validation is called when I want to use `$this->Job->save()`, but I don't use this in my action.

Unfortunately this does not work. When I submit my form without selecting any checkboxes, it let's me do that and if I look at the `$this->validationErrors` array, it is empty. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have updated my question. I hope it's more descriptive now.

Comment: Basically after I submit this form I make a cURL request and if that does not fail then I create a Job with the returned ID. And here of course I use $this->Job->save(), but there the system_codes_filter field can be empty (null), but at submission the user selects those system that he wants to include in his job, so if he selects all the systems then the system_codes_filter will be null in the database, but I should not allow the user to not select any system code on the web page.

Comment: There is still no controller action code in the question (what _are_ you using?) and the data you're submitting isn't in the question either.